# ABD status and tenure-track positions hiring

Tags: thesis, job, tenure-track

If a competitive Ph.D. Candidate who is ABD (All but dissertation) wants to apply to tenure-track positions despite still working on their thesis; how many months do universities usually leave for those candidates to defend and graduate after the start of the tenure-track position?

Comment: My old institution in Switzerland once hired an (outstanding) assistant professor months before they had actually defended their PhD. HR was thoroughly displeased since there was no employment category that even remotely fit, but the department head pushed and prevailed. Many things are possible if sufficiently important players in the department want to make them happen, but that doesn't mean that they are easy or likely to happen.

Answer (score 13):

More generally, not just for tenure-track positions, jobs that require a PhD typically require you do have a PhD **before starting work**. That doesn't mean they won't go through the hiring process beforehand, but they're going to expect that before you start your job you can say you have the degree.

Some exceptions may be granted for *administrative* processing; for example, if you are able to complete your defense and *all* degree requirements but your institution only grants degrees at the end of semesters, you may find someone that will consider you as having effectively graduated.

"All But Dissertation", though, also means you are "Anything But a Doctor". **Someone ABD has not earned their degree yet**. The successful completion of a thesis defense is a pretty integral part of the PhD process, I wouldn't expect anyone to take it so lightly as assuming it's a mere formality. Additionally, taking a job in the meantime seems like it would increase the risk that the thesis and defense are *never* finished. The time starting out as a tenure-track faculty member is an especially stressful time, with many responsibilities that do not include finishing and defending a thesis.

Like most things, though, it's ultimately up to any individual institution unless there are specific laws that bind them.

Comment: ABD is generally meant to be "All but dissertation", meaning someone has defended their work but the thesis still needs to be finished and approved.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  I've typically seen [ABD used when someone has completed all their non-dissertation tasks: any required courses or preliminary examinations, and any other degree requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_but_dissertation). That is, it would not typically indicate someone has already defended, though it could. In any event, the point I wanted to emphasize is that "ABD" means someone hasn't finished their degree.

Comment: In my experience, also, in the U.S., in math, "ABD" does _not_ include the defense...

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Never heard it used that way

Comment: I have only heard of ABD as standing for "all but dissertation" and this is the meaning of this abbreviation in the question.

Comment: @TerryLoring Sorry, maybe this is what Wolfgang meant, too, I was just making a joke with the abbreviation. I know what it's meant to stand for, but it also tends to be overused by some people to exaggerate accomplishments, when it really just means that the absolutely most important part of your degree isn't done yet.

Comment: @BryanKrause Apparently people use the term in different ways then :-) In any case, the OP was clear in their question. It did note the little joke and appreciated it!

Comment: @Bryan Krause I got your point, finally.  You are correct that ABD is a often used to exaggerate  .

Comment: I got offered my current position before completing my defense. In my offer, it stated that if I didn't finish my degree before the start date, I would be placed in a non-tenure track position. Then I would automatically be appointed to a tenure-track position when my degree was complete. Fortunately I managed to graduate beforehand.

Comment: Given the competition for faculty positions, let alone ones on tenure track, I find it hard to imagine that many colleges or universities would even interview an ABD, let alone make a job offer.

Comment: @Llaves The commenter right above you is one example. In some fields and for some positions (especially at primarily instructional rather than research institutions) it's common to hire people directly out of PhDs, in others it's completely unheard of and everyone does some sort of postdoctoral position. For those who hire without post doc experience, it's likely that almost everyone they interview does not have their degree quite yet.

Comment: @BryanKrause - yes, I saw that comment. But that doesn't alter the fact that this is rare, as the first line of your answer suggests. The OP asks how long they might be given after starting work to complete their thesis. As your answer states, most institutions expect the candidate to complete their degree before beginning work. My comment suggests that it would be rare for someone not expecting to be done before the start date to even be interviewed, implicitly for this very reason.

Comment: @Llaves I agree with you there: "it would be rare for someone not expecting to be done before the start date to even be interviewed"- but that's different from not interviewing them before the degree is granted, as interviews can be months before the position starts.

Comment: @BryanKrause - this all comes back to what ABD means. In the dark ages 50 years ago when I got my PhD, ABD pretty much meant you had finished all your coursework and still had to write a dissertation. It typically suggested a much longer time to completion than the time between interviewing and the start date of the position. Those interviewing for academic positions interviewed on the basis of their thesis research and were able to present significant results. Given that competition for academic positions has only increased since then, I'd expect even stricter completion requirements.

Comment: @Llaves I think it depends on field a bit. In fields that have a lot of external funding for research, it's often necessary to have several years of additional research experience to build a sufficient resume for tenure-track. OP mentioned in another post that they're in the social sciences - lot of variation there, but in some of the social sciences far fewer people will ever be post docs than are professors, there is isn't any money for it, so no matter the competition level the people just graduating have the best academic resume they'll ever have unless hired as a professor.